# Remove duplicate custom data elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have elements with a custom data attribute called data-solutionid. It can happen that multiple elements with the same data-solutionid appear. I want to remove duplicate elements.

My html is:

```
<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13000">
    <h4>Solution 1</h4>
    <p>Description</p>
    <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13001">
    <h4>Solution 2</h4>
    <p>Description</p>
    <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13000">
    <h4>Solution 1</h4>
    <p>Description</p>
    <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13002">
    <h4>Solution 3</h4>
    <p>Description</p>
    <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13002">
    <h4>Solution 3</h4>
    <p>Description</p>
    <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>
```

I want to remove the duplicates so that I end up only with unique elements like so:

```
<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13000">
    <h4>Solution 1</h4>
    <p>Description</p>
    <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13001">
    <h4>Solution 2</h4>
    <p>Description</p>
    <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13002">
    <h4>Solution 3</h4>
    <p>Description</p>
    <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var seen = {};
$( '[data-solutionid]').each(function() {
    var dataID = $(this).data();
    if (seen[dataID])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        seen[dataID] = true;
});
```

However for reasons I do not understand, my code removed all elements except one.

Comment: *It can happen that multiple elements with the same data-solutionid appear*. How are they appearing? It could be better to prevent any duplicates to appear instead of removing them later on, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer might be one that prevents any duplicates from appearing. But the following will help you fix your current issue.

When using the [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method you'll need to specify the data attribute you want to get. Right now it is empty and that will return an object with data attribute data.

Using `$(this).data('solutionid')` will use the value of the `data-solutionid` attribute and fix your logic.

```js
var seen = {};
$('[data-solutionid]').each(function() {
  var dataID = $(this).data('solutionid');
  if (seen[dataID])
    $(this).remove();
  else
    seen[dataID] = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13000">
  <h4>Solution 1</h4>
  <p>Description</p>
  <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13001">
  <h4>Solution 2</h4>
  <p>Description</p>
  <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13000">
  <h4>Solution 1</h4>
  <p>Description</p>
  <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13002">
  <h4>Solution 3</h4>
  <p>Description</p>
  <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13002">
  <h4>Solution 3</h4>
  <p>Description</p>
  <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vanilla JS solution. First we'll select just the divs with the target `dataset`. Then we'll just track the found solutionids and remove any that match one that's been found with:

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
```

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-solutionid]`), found = [], id
for (let x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
  id = divs[x].dataset.solutionid
  if (found.indexOf(id) !== -1) divs[x].parentNode.removeChild(divs[x])
  else found.push(id);
}
```

```css
.solutionitem {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13000">
  <h4>Solution 1</h4>
  <p>Description</p>
  <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13001">
  <h4>Solution 2</h4>
  <p>Description</p>
  <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13000">
  <h4>Solution 1</h4>
  <p>Description</p>
  <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13002">
  <h4>Solution 3</h4>
  <p>Description</p>
  <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="solutionitem" data-solutionid="13002">
  <h4>Solution 3</h4>
  <p>Description</p>
  <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>


<div class="solutionitem">
  <h4>Ignore ME</h4>
  <p>Description</p>
  <a href="/something">Link</a>
</div>
```

I see you're using jQuery. For what it's worth, this solution works either way.